# Auto number name shows up null in the test class

Tags: unit-test

I have a custom object where record name is auto generated. In a test class I am creating a record of that object and then calling another method from another class where this record is being used. That method throws error saying "Argument cannot be null". The created record has no name (or null name).

I cannot do record.Name = 'Test' as it shows an error saying "Field is not writable".

Any idea why the record name is null in the test class and how I solve it?

Code:

```
@isTest
private class MyTestClass {
    private static testMethod void test() {
        CustomObj__c obj = new CustomObj__c();
        obj.Field1__c = 'value';
        //so on
        insert obj;

        Boolean flag = SomeClassThatUsesCustomObj.StaticMethod(obj);
        System.assertsEqual(true, flag);
    }
}
```

When the static method of the SomeClassThatUsesCustomObj is running, it needs the name of the obj record. But since it is auto number, it comes out to be null and hence throws an exception and the test class fails.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the code?

Comment: I have added a sample code.

Comment: As specified in  One of the answers below, you simply have to query again for the name field after doing the insert.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to mock an SObject with an auto-number field pre-filled in, do the following

```
Foo__c foo = (Foo__c) Json.deserialize('{"name" : "abc"}',Foo__c.class);
```

This is an object in memory, not in the database. You can add additional fields to mock in the JSON string expression.

Note that the JSON value for "name" doesn't even have to adhere to the auto-number format for the object.

**UPDATE - when you need to insert the mocked SObject**

```
@isTest
private class MyTestClass {
    private static testMethod void test() {
        CustomObj__c obj = new CustomObj__c();
        obj.Field1__c = 'value';
        //so on
        insert obj;
        obj = [select id, field1__c, name from CustomObj__c where id = :obj.id LIMIT 1]; // add this line

        Boolean flag = SomeClassThatUsesCustomObj.StaticMethod(obj);
        System.assertsEqual(true, flag);
    }
}
```

Auto-number field values of mocked SObjects must be queried before they can be referenced later in the code path.  Note that @FernandoGavinho had this answer first

Comment: So do I do this when I am creating the record in my test class? Foo__c foo = (Foo__c) Json.deserialize('{"name" : "abc"}',Foo__c.class);  foo.field__c = 'value'; insert foo;  then call the other class which uses foo?

Comment: no - technique only works if you are not inserting - I thought that was your issue.  If inserting, do the insert and then query the record to get the value of the autonumber field(s) as @FernandoGavinho suggested

Comment: I have added a sample code that explains my situation.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: appreciate your help @crop1645

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem with that field. I solved it by querying the name field after the insert

Comment: The solution works for you cause you might be manually supplying the name field to the calling method. In my case, I need to supply the entire record to a method where it is processed.

Comment: @codeinprogress - Then you need to either put the code that calls the static method in a trigger or query for the entire object then pass it to the code.